# Document size implies "parseError occured"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I have a collection looking like :

```
{
 date:"20150730",
 store:"X",
 catalogue : [{...}, ..., {...}] // ~3000 items
},
{
 date:"20150807",
 store:"X",
 catalogue : [{...}, ..., {...}] // ~3000 items
},
{
 date:"20150807",
 store:"Y",
 catalogue : [{...}, ..., {...}] // ~25000 items
}
```

And the query i intent to do is :

```
collection.findOne({store:_store},{"sort":{'date':-1}}, function(err,doc){
    doc && console.log(doc);
    err && console.log(err);
});
```

which i would like to translate as "get me the most recent document of _store" (1st question is **Am I right ?**)

Then, if I try the query on store X, it works perfectly but on store Y, it throws me :

```
[Error: parseError occured]
```

More info :

```
Object.bsonsize(db.ZeCollection.findOne({store:"X"}))
```

-> 845994

```
Object.bsonsize(db.ZeCollection.findOne({store:"Y"}))
```

-> 7351092

All documents are valid JSON

Mongodb wrapper for node.js is `mongojs` (npm install mongojs)

**Do you have any clue about this issue ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was indeed a mongojs issue.

Mongojs close the connection pool while retrieving large data.

But good news : Mongojs solved this problem.

So i just had to do `npm update mongojs`and everything is working fine now.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as this (with Mongoose), look at `sort`and `exec`:

```
collection.findOne({store:_store}).sort({'date':-1}).exec(function (err, doc) {
    //Do something
});
```

**UPDATE**:

So, in `mongojs` your code is wrong you should have instead:

```
collection.findOne({store: _store}).sort({'date':-1}, function (err, doc) {
    //Do something
});
```

As stated here: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#usage

Comment: then how is it working for {store : 'X'} as you said?

Comment: Well, i think `sort` function is working with a cursor but `findOne` returns a document.
Also, exec is not a function of mongojs. (Mongoose perhaps) ?

Comment: Nope... First, sort is working with a cursor, so your answer should be

`collection.find({store: _store}).sort({'date':-1}, function (err, docS) {
    //Do something
});`

and to approach what i want, it should be : 

    `collection.find({store:_store}).sort({'date':-1}).limit(1).toArray(function (err, docs) {
  docs && console.log(docs[0].date+" "+docs[0].magasin);
  err && console.log(err);
 });` 



Now worst part :


`collection.findOne({store:"X"});  // working
collection.findOne({store:"Y"});  // not working`

Same queries with robomongo : both work

Comment: ... can't we write a beautiful comment ? -_-'

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb, you would use the following query in order to recover the last date of a store XXXX:

```
db.collection('collection').group({
  "key": {"store": true},
  "initial": {},
  "reduce": function(obj, prev){
    prev.max_date = isNaN(prev.max_date) ? obj.date : Math.max(prev.max_date, obj.date);
  },
  "cond": {"store":"XXXXXX"}
  }
)
```

Then, you can recover anything that you want, because you already have the store and the last date.
In mongojs the syntax would be:

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('X.X.X.X/database');

db.collection('collection').group({
  "key": {"store": true},
  "initial": {},
  "reduce": function(obj, prev){
   prev.max_date = isNaN(prev.max_date) ? obj.date : Math.max(prev.max_date, obj.date);},
  "cond": {"store":"XXXXXX"}
  },
  function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
  }
)
```